# Setting HTML tag's class based on mongo result in meteor

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, meteor, spacebars

I'm building a list-group that contains exceptions and warnings thrown out by a back-end device. The `list-group` reads off a collection with a field called '`type`'. This type field can contain warnings or errors. Based on warnings / errors, how do I set `list-group-item-danger` / `list-group-item-warning` in meteor?

**Mongo Collection looks like this:**

```
{ type:"red", timestamp: new Date(), message:"something happened 3"}
```

**My list-group-item looks like this:**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> {{ message }}
        <div class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>{{timestamp}}</em>
        </div>
    </a>
```

How do I incorporate a `list-group-item` list-group-item-danger`based on`type = red` returned by mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it figured out with help from the meteor forum.

**Template:**

```
...
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alertModal" class="{{listGroupClass}} clearfix">
...
```

**Helper:**

```
Template.alert.helpers ({
    listGroupClass: function() {
        if (this.type == "red") {
            return "list-group-item list-group-item-danger";
        }else
        if (this.type == "warning") {
            return "list-group-item list-group-item-warning";
        }else
        if (this.type == "info") {
            return "list-group-item list-group-item-info";
        }
    }


});
```